# Netsuite SuiteTalk API GET Index Not Returning Full Resource

Tags: javascript, api, netsuite

I'm totally confused.. I finally got the SuiteTalk API working and am able to make authenticated calls from my JS server..

I'm calling the GET /invoice route, which documented here:

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2022.2/index.html#tag-invoice

Says that it should return to me an InvoiceCollection which is a collection of Invoices which, by the documentation, has all the fields I need as part of an Invoice.

However, the actual response I am getting back is just an array of items that only has the ID in it.. where are all the other invoice fields?!

I tried to just fire off subsequent calls to the /invoice/{id} route with each ID, but I am getting back some of them as unauthorized and some not.. assuming having to do with timestamp being to close together or something.

There has to be a way to call up to /invoice and get all of the data having to do with an invoice and not just the ID right?

I'm also wondering how I can utilize the "Q" param to filter to invoices only for a certain customer, or date, etc. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying all these queries in postman (netsuite provides a collection for it). If you try it there, you'll see that {{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/invoice  returns a list of id's and links to invoices.

If you dont see the details of an invoice, can that have something to do with the rights (to that subsidiary)?

e.g. GET: {{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/invoice/164198 shows me the entire record.

To get invoices from a certain customer i think i would go for a query in the suiteql restlet.

Hope that helps a bit. I'm just discovering suitetalk myself and it's not the easiest to get a grip of.